# What is the best method to create form in iOS application?

Tags: ios7

I am newbie to iOS application.  I have to create 5 view controllers for 5 forms.

How will navigate to each other using code?

Is it correct way to create 5 view controllers for 5 forms?

Any idea or link should be appreciate.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you want to do this using the storyboard interface builder in XCode 5. Basically you want to create 5 viewcontroller objects which each contains UIViews for your form such as buttons, text areas, scrollviews, etc. You want to have a way of jumping from one viewcontroller to another. Technically you could right click a UIButton and drag its action event to the next viewcontroller and select modal. A much better method would be to put your first viewcontroller inside a navigationbarcontroller, which can done using the toolbar buttons: Editor > Nest in.. when you have that first viewcontroller selected. For navigation bars you mostly have your 'Next' Button (UINavigationBarButton) in the top right and right click that > action and drag that event to the next viewcontroller (select push when prompted).